# Return value from socket.io

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, node.js, socket.io

Here i am using node js and socket.io for my website.i want return value of 'newString' while executing the below function.Now i am getting correct value for 'newString' inside the function.But i need it outside the function.

```
<script>
function createSocketPlayList(){
    var page            =   'notification_playlist';
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000', { query: "from=<?php echo $_SESSION['userId']?>&page="+page });
    socket.on('notification_playlist', function (data_playlist) {
        var usersList_playlist    = "";
        var musicTitle            = "";
        var myPlaylist            = "";
        $.each(data_playlist.users_playlist,function(index,user){
                musicTitle        = "<?php echo addslashes($objCommon->html2text($allMyPlayList['music_title']))?>";
                usersList_playlist +=   "{ ";
                usersList_playlist +=   "mp3:'<?php echo SITE_ROOT?>uploads/music/"+user.music_url+"',title:'"+musicTitle+" ',artist:'Sanjeev Darshan | © Eros International Media Ltd',rating:4, buy:'#',price:'0.99',duration:'',cover:'<?php echo SITE_ROOT?>uploads/music/"+user.music_thumb+"',releaseddate:'17-05-2015'";
                usersList_playlist +=   " },";  
        });
        var newString = usersList_playlist.substr(0, usersList_playlist.length-1); 
    });

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I have added an extra function (updatePlayList) so you have the playlist "out".

You need to re-arrange your code so it has the subscribe call (socket.on) and playlist building method (createSocketPlayList) separated like this:

```
var page = 'notification_playlist';
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000', { query: "from=<?php echo $_SESSION['userId']?>&page="+page });

socket.on('notification_playlist', updatePlayList);

function updatePlayList(data_playlist) {
    var playlist = createSocketPlayList(data_playlist);
    // Update your list wherever it is on the page.
}

function createSocketPlayList(data_playlist){
    var usersList_playlist    = "";
    var musicTitle            = "";
    var myPlaylist            = "";
    $.each(data_playlist.users_playlist,function(index,user){
            musicTitle        = "<?php echo addslashes($objCommon->html2text($allMyPlayList['music_title']))?>";
            usersList_playlist +=   "{ ";
            usersList_playlist +=   "mp3:'<?php echo SITE_ROOT?>uploads/music/"+user.music_url+"',title:'"+musicTitle+" ',artist:'Sanjeev Darshan | © Eros International Media Ltd',rating:4, buy:'#',price:'0.99',duration:'',cover:'<?php echo SITE_ROOT?>uploads/music/"+user.music_thumb+"',releaseddate:'17-05-2015'";
            usersList_playlist +=   " },";  
    });
    return usersList_playlist.substr(0, usersList_playlist.length-1); 
}
```